# Trouble with posting XML data to ASP.NET MVC from Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have problem sending XML data fron Ajax to ASP.NET MVC. Data is not sent.
Ajax code:

```
`function SendXmlToServer(ServerXml) {
       $.ajax({ url: "/Home/XmlData",
           type: "POST",
            processData: false, 
           data: { ResXml: ServerXml }, dataType: "xml",
           success: function () {
               alert("Successful");
               return false;
           }
       })
   }`
```

ASP.NET MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult XmlData(string ResXml) 
    {   
        return null;
    }
```

Why ResXml variable has null?

Answer (score 0):

The default model binding doesn't work with `processData` set to `false`.  If `ServerXml` is a string of XML, removing this should make it work:

```
function SendXmlToServer(ServerXml) {
   $.ajax({ url: "/Home/XmlData",
       type: "POST",
       data: { ResXml: ServerXml }, dataType: "xml",
       success: function () {
           alert("Successful");
           return false;
       }
   });
}
```

You'll also have to add the `ValidateInput` attribute to your action method, because normally "HTML markup" isn't allowed:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult XmlData(string ResXml) 
{   
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use custom model binding to seamlessly deserialize the XML, as explained in [this blog post](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/24/model-binding-xml-in-asp-net-mvc-3/).