# Posting Xml data from jquery ajax to Asp.Net Mvc Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How to post xml data (eg: <firstName>Nitesh</firstName>) to asp.net controller using jquery ajax? 
**Note: argument(s)**  of method in controller must not be the **string** , it must be  **XmlDocument** or any other class capable of **handling xml data only**

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you have tried? Also there seem to be quite a few posts related to this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36473998/1554860) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17535912/1554860) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45188788/1554860) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223042/1554860)

Comment: JAMEZ....   what you have given, its correct but I want to pass the XML data from jquery ajax(contentType: "text/xml") without any conversion to string, and accepting data in xml format only in controller's method

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: 1) Jquery ajax call  =  
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetData1",
            data: "<test></test>",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });

Comment: 2)Controller's method=  [HttpPost]
        public string GetData1(XmlDocument fc) {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fc);                
                return "xyz";
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.Write(ex);
                return ex.ToString();
            }
            
        }